# JSP/Tomcat site has Checksum error but works in Firefox/Chrome Incognito

Tags: jsp, tomcat, kerberos

We have a legacy JSP/Tomcat application that has been running fine until a recent AD update. Since that occurred, this has been returning the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
type Exception report

message GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:233)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
root cause

GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:856)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:906)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:229)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
root cause

KrbException: Checksum failed
    sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:102)
    sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:94)
    sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:175)
    sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:281)
    sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:829)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:906)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:229)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
root cause

java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
    sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.ArcFourCrypto.decrypt(ArcFourCrypto.java:408)
    sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmac.decrypt(ArcFourHmac.java:91)
    sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:100)
    sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(ArcFourHmacEType.java:94)
    sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:175)
    sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:281)
    sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
    sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:829)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:906)
    sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:556)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
    sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
    net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:229)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
```

We have noticed that this site will work if you hit in in either Chrome's Incognito Mode or in Firefox. However, both of those will prompt for login credentials first. This seems to be something in the realm of Kerberos encryption type issues or something similar, however I have not been able to find any accounts of this behavior of it working when prompted for authentication. Will this force Kerberos to behave differently? If so, how do I know what it is doing in either scenario? If not, is there something different about how these credentials are authenticated that could be causing a different issue here? Here is what our krb5.conf file looks like:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts arcfour-hmac
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts arcfour-hmac
    permitted_enctypes   = aes256-cts aes128-cts arcfour-hmac
    default_realm = CONTOSO.COM
    forwardable = true

[realms]
    CONTOSO.COM  = {
        kdc = ADSERVER1.CONTOSO.COM
        kdc = ADSERVER2.CONTOSO.COM
        kdc = ADSERVER3.CONTOSO.COM
        default_domain = CONTOSO.COM 
}

[domain_realm]
    .CONTOSO.COM = CONTOSO.COM
```

Comment: Are you sure that when the browsers prompt for authentication, they actually do Kerberos at all and not just fall back to 'Basic' authentication?